# Autolayout doesn't work?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

So I'm creating my app in storyboard, and i'm using an navigation controller, added an add view, and trying to auto layout stuff there.

But the problem is, i only get blue guided lines when I'm near the corner left and right. So it's basically not looking at my Navigationbar above.. and just ignoring it.

Also, when I'm switching the simulator to a 3.5 inch (I'm making it in 4 inch) the buttons and labels will disappear underneath it. And they are added to Auto layout blue lines?

[image: No blue lines to the top.]

Comment: you have to establish the autolayout constraints either manually or by letting xcode define them. They are not established just by putting an control onto the view!

Answer (score 1):

The blue lines are not AutoLayout, but just lines that guide you when placing your views. Auto Layout only comes in when you start adding constraints. Check out Apple's Autolayout guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Control drag from the `label` to the `navigation bar` and it will show the below window. The first option is for you to create the constraint from the Navigation Bar bottom.

[image]

The `Top Layout Guide` is a iOS 7 specific feature which marks the bottom line of the navigation bar. The total height of the navigation bar (if present) plus the height of the status bar (if present) equals the `toplayoutGuide.length`